# Aurora replica readonly converted to writer now working as multimaster

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Today while auditing we found that Aurora Read Replica is upgraded to Role Writer and master DB as Role reader in Cluster, I can create tables in both server and the replicated to each other so its working as multi master server.

How can I change the role again Also why Aurora do this I can't find any event related to it. DB parameter Read_only Value `{TrueIfReplica}` In Status it shows `read_Only = OFF`.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change the role back by 'Failover' (from Instance Actions drop-down menu) of the writer. It might have happened because of a previous failover.

Answer (score 1):

That is really not possible as we know master-master is not an easy configuration and we need to configure it explicitly.

Are you saying that u created a table on one master and it got available in other master and vice-versa ? That is master-master...

or are you simply saying that you can write to both the servers.. in that case; they have just diverged and are now independent aurora servers

Comment: Yes its possible , I saw it if i create and insert data in one then it got in 2nd , if i do it on 2nd it goes to 1st, i don't know is it bug or what , but i have to delete the 2nd one and aws promoted the master again in front then i recreate 2nd as read replica.